# Math needed to understand hodge star operator

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm a physics student trying to understand the hodge star operator and how to use it to derive the Laplacian. I looked into it, but the math language used is complete jibberish (notation seems insanely prohibitive). What exact field does the hodge star pertain to? Can you list the things I need to know in order to learn about this/books to read?

Comment: isn't for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator a good enough start?

Comment: It depends on the level at which you want to understand it. (ie. on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a general Riemannian manifold) The Youtuber Micheal Penn has a [nice playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7) of videos on the basics of differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which covers the hodge star operator in detail.

Comment: I would study Riemannian manifolds (at least the basics) before covering the operator. Sounds like you are going in blind.

Comment: Consider the physicist-friendly books: *A visual introduction to differential forms* by J.P. Fortney and *Gauge fields, knots, and gravity* by Baez

Comment: I'd suggest Chapter 2 of Jost's Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Hodge star operator belongs to the subject of [multilinear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_algebra), or perhaps [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra).  (The Wikipedia page on "exterior algebra" is probably the more helpful of the previous two.)  Typically, one first encounters the Hodge star in a course on [calculus on manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), or a course on [Riemannian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold).

If you're interested in a having a clear mathematical understanding of the Hodge star, then you'll need to know (at minimum) what the following concepts mean:

- Vector space $V$
- Dual space $V^*$ (of a vector space)
- Inner product $\langle v,w\rangle$ of vectors $v,w \in V$.
- Orientation of a vector space.
- Multilinear map $\omega \colon \underbrace{V \times \cdots \times V}_{k} \to \mathbb{R}$.  By slight abuses of terminology and notation, a multilinear map (involving $k$ copies of $V$) is called an **(algebraic) $k$-form**, and the set of multilinear maps ($k$-forms) is often denoted by $\Lambda^k(V^*)$.
- Wedge product $\alpha \wedge \beta$ of a $k$-form $\alpha$ and an $\ell$-form $\beta$.

Now, suppose you understand the above words.  If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional real vector space --- so you can think of $V$ as $\mathbb{R}^n$ --- equipped with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and an orientation, then one can define (but I won't define it here) the **Hodge star** operator
$$\ast \colon \Lambda^k(V^*) \to \Lambda^{n-k}(V^*).$$
Note that if $\alpha \in \Lambda^k(V^*)$ is a $k$-form on $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\ast \alpha \in \Lambda^{n-k}(V^*)$ is an $(n-k)$-form on $V = \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Standard Example:** Taking $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ with its standard inner product and orientation, letting $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ be the standard basis, and $\{e^1, e^2, e^3\}$ be the dual basis of $V^* = (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$, then:
\begin{align*}
\ast e^1 & = e^2 \wedge e^3 \\
\ast e^2 & = e^3 \wedge e^1 \\
\ast e^3 & = e^1 \wedge e^2
\end{align*}

**Remark:** It turns out that the the gradient and divergence operators (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), as well as the curl operator (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), can all be expressed in terms of three concepts: the Hodge star operator, the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), and the [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).  Using those formulas, one can derive a similar formula for the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

Now, if you are interested in the Laplacian in even greater generality --- e.g., on a (possibly curved) Riemannian $n$-manifold $M$ --- then of course you'll need to know more words, such as:

- Manifold
- Tangent space
- Riemannian metric
- Volume form

When one speaks of the Hodge star operator on a Riemannian manifold $M$, what one really means is the Hodge star operator $\ast$ on the tangent spaces $T_pM$ of $M$.  In other words, the Hodge star operator at a point $p \in M$ is defined to be the Hodge star operator on the vector space $V = T_pM$.

Comment: Thank you for including the prerequisites, and (from what I currently understand) great explanation. I was just curious, how did you learn about this area, was it entirely in classes, or did you do more independent reading on your own?

Comment: @MondoDuke I think this video series by eigenchris might be a good start to (multi-)linear algebra : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ptMTLzV4-I&list=PLJHszsWbB6hrkmmq57lX8BV-o-YIOFsiG&ab_channel=eigenchris

Answer (score 0):

Hodge start operation comes from the concept of differential k-forms of differential geometry,
You don't really need to learn it by studying differential geometry,
in fact, you can master it totally by algebra.

The definition of a k-form is very straight-forward.
just a multi-linear and alternative mapping $w: T_pR^n \rightarrow R$

Then by this simple definition, you can derive all the property of differential forms including the hodge star operator and all the related attribute.

I have done some of that in one of my blog but it is written by Chinese.
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/681207592

or this video series has a clear introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDRfADusqYQ&list=PL22w63XsKjqzQZtDZO_9s2HEMRJnaOTX7&index=20
in fact, I learned it from that seris.

in fact, when you master the k-differential form, you can even guess what a hodge star operation is.
because it maps a k-form to n-k form, then it is easy to think it maps dx to $dy\wedge dz$ in $R^3$ and in fact, it is.